# Filter touchscreen events

Tags: android, filtering, touchscreen

My android application should work in envioriment with lots of EMI. Unfortunately EMI sometimes triggers touchscreen events. Those triggers seems to be random, so it's possible to filter them out.

I want to create overlay window that receives all touchscreen events, filters them and passes to my activity's controls or system's statusbar.

I've created transparent overlay window to have something to start with:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,                 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,               
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);           


    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.touch_filter_overlay, null);
    wm.addView(mTopView, wmParams);
```

I think I can subclass ViewGroup to receive messages, but how can I then send processed messages to background controls?

Maybe there is another solution to my problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The false screen detection and filtering is also the responsibility of the touch screen sensor, on the electronics component.
Some touch screen sensors are using dedicated electronics filters, plus high-end filtering algorithms to reject the false touches.
That's why I suggest you change your smartphone, and find one that is EMI proof.